# Problems executing cypress more than once and save results in different screenshotsFolder in Cypress version 12.10.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, web, cypress

I'm trying to create a folder to save the screenshots I capture from Cypress in a custom folder inside screenshots, where in the screenshotFolder folder, a folder with the date will be added dynamically for each execution of run.cypress(), but it's not working.

The problem is that when the code run.cypress() is executed, at the end it changes the route that I put and leaves the one that is by default.

The code can be executed, and it is the follow:

```
const cypress = require('cypress');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('node:path'); 

//Function that create the test run
var createRunTest = async function (info, folderNameResults){

   //Datetime will be modified every time that the function is called
   var datetime2 = new Date(); //test start date
   datetime2 = datetime2.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', '_');
   datetime2 = datetime2.replace(/:\s*/g, '_');

   //Then I create the folders of the results for reports and screenshots with the number of execution and his datetime
   //Creation datetime folder in reports (time it runs)
   var reportsFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'cypress', 'reports', folderNameResults, cronInfo.execution_num + '_' + datetime2);
   fs.mkdir(reportsFolder, (err) => {
       if (err) {
          if (err.code == 'EEXIST') return console.error("file exist");
          return console.error(err);
       }
   });

   //Creation datetime folder in screenshots (time it runs)
   var screenshotsFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'cypress', 'screenshots', folderNameResults, info.execution_num + '_' + datetime2);
   fs.mkdir(screenshotsFolder, (err) => { 
       if (err) {
          if (err.code == 'EEXIST') return console.error("file exist");
          return console.error(err);
       }
   });


   console.log("It should be: ", screenshotsFolder);

   let results = await cypress.run({
       browser: 'chrome',
       configFile: __dirname + '/cypress.config.js',
       spec: __dirname + '/cypress/e2e/investigation/testWeb.cy.js', //put your test here
       reporter: "cypress-multi-reporters",
       reporterOptions: {
           "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
           "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
               "reportDir": reportsFolder + "/json/",
               "overwrite": false,
               "html": false,
               "json": true
           }
       },
       videosFolder: __dirname + '/cypress/videos',
       screenshotsFolder: screenshotsFolder,
   });
   console.log("But it is this", results.config.screenshotsFolder);

   info.execution_num += 1;

   return;
}



//Here i have information of execution times
var info = {
    id: 1
    created: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
    execution_num: 0, //execution number
}

var folderNameResults = info.id + '_' + info.created;


//here i create a folder with folderNameResults in directories "cypress/reports/ and cypress/screenshots"
//i.e. remaining as follow: cypress/reports/1_05_17_2023 (and the same with screenshots)

fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/cypress/reports/' + folderNameResults, (err) => { //creation in REPORTS
    if (err) {
        if (err.code == 'EEXIST') return console.error("file exist");
        return console.error(err);
    }
});

fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/cypress/screenshots/' + folderNameResults, (err) => { //creation in SCREENSHOTS
    if (err) {
        if (err.code == 'EEXIST') return console.error("file exist");
        return console.error(err);
    }
});


//Then i call the function to create a execution test
console.log("FIRST EXECUTION"); //increment +1 execution number (1)
createRunTest(info, folderNameResults).then( () => {
    console.log("SECOND EXECUTION");
    //increment +1 execution number (2)
    createRunTest(info, folderNameResults);
});
```

In the first execution the Output is, that show me that doesn't work:

```
It should be:  C:\Users\xeom\Desktop\Ayudantia\v2_script\script/cypress/screenshots/1_2023-05-17/0_2023-05-17_19_32_30

But it is this C:\Users\xeom\Desktop\Ayudantia\v2_script\script\cypress\screenshots
```

So what happens with this is what appears in the following image:
[image: Problems with screenshots folders in cypress]

The file with the captures that should be for each execution is stored outside the folders that you create and is also overwritten in the testWeb.cy.js folder (there should be a folder named like this for each execution folder).

Also, we can see that with reports it work pretty good.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screenshotsFolder` should be in the `config` section

```
let results = await cypress.run({
    browser: 'chrome',
    configFile: __dirname + '/cypress.config.js',
    //spec: __dirname + '/cypress/e2e/investigacion/testWeb.cy.js',
    reporter: "cypress-multi-reporters",
    reporterOptions: {
        "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
        "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
            "reportDir": "cypress/reports/" + folderName + '/' + datetime + "/json/",
            //"reportDir": "cypress/reports/json/",
            "overwrite": false,
            "html": false,
            "json": true
        }
    },
    config:{
       videosFolder: __dirname + '/cypress/videos',
       screenshotsFolder: screenshotsFolder
    }
});
```

[code](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/adc4c5e32cf481869097ac796b5e4734cb25b91c/cli/types/cypress-npm-api.d.ts#L141) source

Comment: I forgot to put something, the code I have is a function, so I would like that every time I call that function it leaves the screenshotFolder in different places within a directory, that's why I have it in that place.

Comment: That is to say that what I want is to execute cypress.run() several times and that in each of them, I have a different folder to save the screenshots.

Comment: I have further detailed the specific problem i am having with cypress.

Answer (score 2):

Wandille is correct, you just set the config in the wrong place - so I suspect you are struggling with the basics.

I recommend using a `before()` to set up the screenshot path, then the change applies not only to Module API calls but also `cypress run` and `cypress open`.

```js
before(() => {
  const folderName = 'ROX';
  const timestamp = (new Date())
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 19)
    .replace('T', '_')
    .replace(/:\s*/g, '_')
  
  const myScreenshotsFolder = `${folderName}/${timestamp}`
  
  Cypress.Commands.overwrite('screenshot', (originalFn, subject, ...args) => {
    let {name, userOptions} = args
    name = `${myScreenshotsFolder}/${(name || Cypress.currentTest.title)}`
    originalFn(subject, name, userOptions)
  })
})
```

Notes:

- the extra path you want `myScreenshotsFolder` is added automatically to base path `cypress/screenshots`
- where your test defines a filename `cy.screenshot('some-file-name')` it will be used, otherwise the test title is used. This follows Cypress current convention.
- the `before()` should go in `cypress/support/e2e.js` file for global use

Comment: Hi, i have further detailed the specific problem i am having with cypress. Although your answer to what you were referring to before was correct, I didn't make myself understand, good. Sorry, now I've put a functional code to give a better explanation of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **start** function from the **Cypress API** and also you can use **path.join** method for defining the folder path.

I have just updated your existing code , You can try with this :-

```js
const path = require('path');

folderName = 'ROX';

var datetime = new Date();
datetime = datetime.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', '_');
datetime = datetime.replace(/:\s*/g, '_');

screenshotsFolder = path.join(__dirname, 'cypress', 'screenshots', folderName, datetime);

console.log("It should be: ", screenshotsFolder);

const cypress = require('cypress');
const { start } = require('cypress/lib/tasks/plugins');

start({
  onBeforeRun: async (options) => {
    options.config.screenshotsFolder = screenshotsFolder;
  },
}).then(async () => {
  const results = await cypress.run({

    browser: 'chrome',
    configFile: __dirname + '/cypress.config.js',
    reporter: "cypress-multi-reporters",
    reporterOptions: {
        "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
        "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
            "reportDir": "cypress/reports/" + folderName + '/' + datetime + "/json/",
            //"reportDir": "cypress/reports/json/",
            "overwrite": false,
            "html": false,
            "json": true
        }
    },
    videosFolder: __dirname + '/cypress/videos',
  });
  
  
});
```

Comment: Hi, the folder plugins in the code: const { start } = require('cypress/lib/tasks/plugins');, doesn't exist.

Comment: hi, i have further detailed the specific problem i am having with cypress.